# Definition of $\Lambda$-adic cusp form

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, modular-forms

Definition 4.2.2 of [https://www.math.arizona.edu/~swc/aws/2018/2018SharifiNotes.pdf](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Eswc/aws/2018/2018SharifiNotes.pdf) defines a $\Lambda$-adic form (where $\Lambda$ is an Iwasawa algebra) to be a cusp form if all but finitely many of its specializations are cusp forms.

However, since cuspidality is given by a vanishing condition, wouldn't such a thing be a cusp form at every specialization? Because something that vanishes at all but finitely many specializations should automatically vanish identically, right?

Comment: The definitions in your text are abstract nonsense. Can you show/construct one adic modular form and its specializations.

Comment: The set of cuspidal points is open and hence dense... but that doesn't mean that every specialisation is cuspidal! On the Galois side, we have an associated Galois representation $\rho_F: G_\mathbb Q\to \mathrm{GL}_2(\Lambda')$. The specialisations amount to reducing $\rho_F$ modulo a prime ideal. The equivalent statement on the Galois side is that $\rho_F\pmod{P_{k, \epsilon}}$ is irreducible for almost all $k, \epsilon$. The fact that "almost all" isn't "all" relates to the fact that there are congruences between Eisenstein series and cusp forms... which is pretty important!